# How do I remove blank spaces in a column value with a SQL function?

Tags: sql

How do I remove blank spaces in a column value (for example, 'N  a    ve   e  n') with a SQL function?

I tried doing with trim function which is not very useful.  Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you post the code you have attempted? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace()`:

```
Select replace(Col, ' ', '')
```